# Load a firefox extension on specific page load

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to create a bootstrapped firefox extension.

I want the firefox extension to get loaded from the startup function in bootstrap.js on a specific page load and want to inject a DOM element on that page.

I just want only this to be done ... so that i am able to detect if my firefox extension is installed in browser or not.

I tried PageMod techniques, but extension is not get loaded.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need your extension to be always loaded, otherwise it couldn't detect when the target Webpage is loaded. It's like Greasemonkey, you can augment Web pages if it is enabled. A second alternative is having two extensions, one for monitoring and triggering the second one. But I don't think that is your case.

If you just want to show an HTML element in a concrete Web page, you should:

1) monitor the changes in the URL. You can add an event listener to the tabs, and access the URL with utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document
2) attach a content script, with the code adding the DOM elements you need.

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({         
   contentScriptFile: "./yourJsFileForAddingTheDomElements.js"
});
```